# Dialogflow (api.ai) show response from webhook in list

Tags: list, dialogflow-es

How do i show the response from web hook in clickable list in dialogflow. I have some dynamic lists coming from webhook , which have to be listed.  I have integrated with facebook messenger , there is no option as list in custom responses . please help me out .

Answer (score 2):

Dialogflow doesn't support Facebook's lists natively, you'll have to create a [custom payload](https://dialogflow.com/docs/rich-messages#custom_payload) when responding to Dialogflow from your webhook and send the data structure for a list as indicated on [Facebook Messenger's developer site](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/send-messages/template/list).

Comment: How do i get the list when i use web demo by embedding iFrame . ?

Comment: Web demo doesn't support rich messaging, including lists, sorry.